# GridView Changing EditIndex on RowEditing then Cancelling Edit yields in ViewState Error

Tags: asp.net, gridview, viewstate, failed-to-load-viewstate

I have a `DataSet1` which has `4 rows` which I bind to `GridView1`.
`GridView1` has an `Edit (image) command`.
When a user clicks on row 1, in the `RowEditing event`, I will  remove a particular row (row 0) in `DataSet1` and update `GridView1`.
`EditIndex` to 0 and rebind `DataSet1` to `GridView1`.

```
GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
GridView1.DataSource = DataSet1;
GridView1DataBind();
```

The problem appears when the user cancels editing. I am getting the error:

```
Failed to load viewstate.  
The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control 
tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.
```

For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

It appears to be because of the mismatch in the original `EditIndex` (row 1) and the new `EditIndex` which I set (row 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The mismatch in ViewState is because while GridView1.EditIndex was updated, the event argument field e.NewEditIndex value (which I'm guessing is updating the ViewState) is not updated. See updated code below that works:

```
GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
e.NewEditIndex = 0;
GridView1.DataSource = DataSet1;
GridView1DataBind();
```